# Raspberry-pi python shell still running older version of python

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am new to linux and somewhat new to python. I am trying to follow a tutorial that is using python 3.9, however I was using python 3.4.2. Once I realized I was out of date I downloaded python 3.9.0 and when I run

```
python -V
```

in the terminal is stats Python 3.9.0, but the python shell is still running 3.4.2

[image]

I am not sure how to change the python version for the current project, or start a new project in python 3.9 when I click on python 3 idle in the menu.

[image]

It still states python 3.4.2

[image]

So how do I get the python idle to run python 3.9.0 and not 3.4.2?

Comment: each python version includes it's own `idle`. Delete the link to that specific one and replace it with the newest version.

Comment: Awesome! That worked! If you put that in an answer I can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 python versions in my PC as well (2 and 3), what I usually do is to add an alias in `~/.bashrc`, and update it when needed, example `alias python="python3"` or if python2 is needed just `alias python="python2"`

Comment: even if I have my Alias set as python=my path, I would still want to do alias python = python3?